# Expirar link php

Tags: php, link, senhas

Gostaria de saber como que eu faço pra expirar um link após um uso.

Temos um sistema de recuperação de senha que envia um e-mail para recuperação que está funcionando perfeitamente. No caso, se o link não for aberto em 30 minutos, ele expira, porém gostaria de saber como fazer este link expirar após o uso, fazendo que ele não possa ser utilizado mais de uma vês, alguém tem uma dica pra dar?

Comment: Pode usar uma flag no banco de dados que ele já foi acessado ou até alterar a data que foi gerado para 30 minutos atrás, assim vai parar de funcionar também.

Answer (score 6):

Acredito que isso pode ser resolvido da seguinte forma:

```
$hora = time(); 
$id = //id qualquer; 
$seulink = "ativacao.php?id=" . $id . "&hora'=" . $hora;
```

E no arquivo ativacao.php você faz a logica para verificar se o parâmetro `$hora` tem uma diferença de mais de meia hora da hora atual. Se for maior, não permite a ativação.

Você também pode gerar uma hash baseada no valor da hora atual e do ID (Para evitar que o usuário mude o valor de `&hora` manualmente) e validar se aquela hash é possível na hora da verificação no ativacao.php.

Já que você quer inutilizar o link depois do primeiro uso, você pode criar uma tabela no banco com duas colunas: `id` e `jaUtilizado` (boolean)  e o `ativacao.php` faria um select no banco pelo id passado via parâmetro na url. Se a coluna `jaUtilizado` estiver marcada para aquele Id a ativacao para naquele ponto. Se não estiver marcado, marca-o e continua com o processo.

Comment: Para casos como esse, sempre é bom o registro no banco de dados.  Como você disse, o usuário pode manipular a url.

Comment: Acho que seria menos custoso fazer o controle disso através de uma hash. Mais ou menos assim:
`$hash = md5($id . $hora . "testehash");`

E então: 

`$seulink = "ativacao.php?id=" . $id . "&hora'=" . $hora . "&hash=" .$hash;`

E aí validar se a hash da url é possível baseado nos inputs de `id` e `hora`.

Comment: Embora isso esteja correto, pelo que entendi o AP já possui está solução, ele necessita agora "bloquear" o link após o usuário utilizar o mesmo.

Comment: Editei a resposta dando uma possível solução.

Answer (score 2):

Com certeza, você terá que salvar essa informação no banco de dados.

Geralmente faço o seguinte:

- Na tabela referente ao usuário, quando o mesmo pede solicitação de recuperação de senha, registro num campo da tabela um hash gerado aleatoriamente.
- Por questão de segurança, não sugiro que coloque a data na url, já que ela pode ser manipulada. É preferível também salvar a data no banco de dados.

O link pode ser assim:

```
meu_site/recupear_senha.php?token=token_que_vem_do_banco_de_dados
```

Em seguida (Código fictício):

```
$token = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'token'); 

 // ou $token = $_GET['token']; //tanto faz

// Compara com a data de -30 minutos atrás
$data_expiracao = (new DateTime('-30 minutes'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 


$resultado = $query->execute("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE token_email  = ? AND data_token >= ?", [$token, $data_expiracao]);

if ($resultado !== false) {

     // Pode confirar nesse token
     // Remove o token de email do banco
     $query->execute('UPDATE usuario WHERE token_email = ? SET token_email = NULL', [$token]);

} else {
   //Expirou, mano! Pede outra solicitação.
}
```

Comment: Para que não entendeu, `-30 minutes` é porque a compração feita é: `Se a data_token for maior ou igual que agora - 30 minutos`. Ou seja, é válido desde agora até 30 minutos a mais. É sempre confuso mexer com datas (pelo menos pra mim é)

Answer (score 2):

Aqui eu fiz um exemplo usando um método de expiração baseado em um intervalo de período:

```
<?php 
    function expireDate($dateStart, $dateEnd) {
        $dateCurrent = new DateTime();

        $dateEnd = new DateTime($dateEnd);
        $dateEnd->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.uO');

        $dateStart = new DateTime($dateStart);
        $dateStart->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.uO');

       if (($dateStart->getTimestamp() <= $dateCurrent->getTimestamp())
          && ($dateEnd->getTimestamp() >= $dateCurrent->getTimestamp())) {
          //enquanto estiver no intervalo ele não expira (retorna falso)
          return false;
       }
       //caso contrário retornará verdadeiro
       return true;
    }
?>
```

E na view:

```
 <?php 
   if(expireDate('2015-10-30 16:00:00', '2015-10-30 16:30:00') != true):
  ?>
   <a href="#">seu link</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Vou testar sim, muito obrigado, posto o resultado depois.

Comment: Serviu perfeitamente para meu uso, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

A melhor forma e guardar um link com um campo data-hora no banco de dados e com um campo bolean para identificar se ja foi usado.

O link no qual o usuario clicka sera entao um link para a rotina que faz um query ao banco. Se o link ainda nao foi usado e esta dentro da hora, entao faz forward, se nao retorna mensagem ou erro.

Comment: Obrigado cou testar aqui, posto o resultado pra vcs depois